# MapKit fix zoom

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

I have mapkit view and i need to fix zoom step. User must only increase or decrease  by 4 times. How i can do it in MapKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map doesn't provide a method to restrict the zoom increment.  I should also say that the default implementation of the map view on the iPhone leads to better user experience I think.  I personally dislike apps that limit my capabilities for no good reason.

To answer your question though, you can manually control your zooming, by disabling [`MKMapView.zoomEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/zoomEnabled) property.  Then you can expose a zoom buttons that change the shown map region, using [`setRegion:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion:animated:).

Here is a sample code on how to zoom the map:

```
-(void)zoomMap:(MKMapView *)map withLevelMultiple:(void)levelMultiplier {
  MKCoordinateRegion region = map.region;
  region.span.latitudeDelta /= levelMultiplier;
  region.span.longitudeDelta /= levelMultiplier;
  [map setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on ways to limit zooming past a certain level that makes sense?